# C++ Windows Unicode REGEX (standard)

Tags: c++, regex, windows

I wrote a piece of code that does REGEX matching of some strings. All well with regular ASCII code but not Unicode.

```
std::string buffer;
/* snip */
const std::tr1::regex rx("([3-9]{1})");
std::tr1::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> res; 
std::tr1::regex_search(buffer, res, rx);
```

Do I have to set locales or whatever to work? Tried something like this but with no success:

```
std::wstring buffer;
/* snip */
const std::tr1::wregex rx("([3-9]{1})");
std::tr1::match_results<std::wstring::const_iterator> res; 
std::tr1::regex_search(buffer, res, rx);
```

Any idea for a simple solution that achieve this?

Comment: Just a side note: regex is part of C++11, so if you switch to this standard version, you can/should write `std::regex` directly.

Comment: So you say that in C++11 `std::regex` will work with UNICODE directly like in my example? Do I have to set locales before or not?

Comment: I don't know how `std::regex` or `std::tr1::regex` work; I just know that it's now part of the standard. It was just a side note in the case you didn't know; nothing which solves your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I know is in standard, I stated it in the question title.

Comment: `wstring` has no inherent connection to Unicode. But that aside, it's not clear what the problem is. There's a syntax error in the argument to the constructor of `rx` in the second snippet; the string should be prefixed with `'L'` to make it a wide-character string. Once that's fixed, the two code snippets do the same thing, the first with ordinary `char` sequences and the second with `wchar_t` sequences.